# No way to populate self eager-loaded relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get loaded one self-relation property eagerly using contains_eager option to avoid two joins when ordering or searching using one of relation columns. My model objects looks as:

```
class Usuario(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}

    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    usuario=Column(Text) 
    ...
    resellers_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('usuarios.id')) 
    ....
    reseller = relation('Usuario', remote_side = [id])
```

I am using to get the data:

```
u= DBSession.query(Usuario).options(contains_eager('reseller'))\
            .outerjoin(self.usuarios_padre, Usuario.resellers_id == self.usuarios_padre.id)\
            .filter(Usuario.id=1)\
            .order_by(self.usuarios_padre.usuario).one()
```

where **self.usuarios_padre** is one alias of Usuario

If I access **u.reseller.usuario** I get the same as **u.usuario** instead getting usuario from parent

Any idea where the problem is? I tryied to define the relation using lazy="joined" without result.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you load two sets of `Usuario` objects in one query, and in order to solve the problem, you need to use the [aliased](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) and then **explicitely** specify the aliased *parent* in both the `join` and the `contains_eager`:

```
qry = session.query(Usuario).filter(Usuario.id==1)

# join using the aliased. Use *outerjoin* in order to still get the result for those without a parent
res = aliased(Usuario)
qry = qry.outerjoin((res, Usuario.reseller))

# specify which table/alias represents the *contained* relationship
qry = qry.options(contains_eager(Usuario.reseller, alias=res))
```